# MsSQL query from remote ubuntu machine to MsSQL database via pymssql is too long

Tags: python, sql-server, azure, ubuntu

My infrastructure is in Microsoft Azure environment. Also, I have an Ubuntu virtual machine on the local network.
First I execute a query in SQL Management Studio and it works in less than a second.
**Then I try to execute the same query with `pymssql` from Ubuntu, which takes about 50 seconds!**

```
import pymssql   
import pandas as pd

qtext = '''
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ids') IS NULL
        SELECT [RichTrackId]
              ,max(PointDate) as max_date
        into #ids
        FROM [MobileServiceStage].[dbo].[RichTrackPoints] (nolock)
        where DeviceToken = 12345
        group by [RichTrackId]

    select 
        rtp.[RichTrackId],
        max(Latitude) as Latitude,
        max(Longitude) as Longitude
    from [MobileServiceStage].[dbo].[RichTrackPoints] as rtp (nolock)
    inner join #ids
    on rtp.DeviceToken = %(user)s and 
        rtp.[RichTrackId] = #ids.[RichTrackId] and rtp.PointDate = #ids.max_date
    group by rtp.[RichTrackId], rtp.PointDate
    order by rtp.PointDate
'''

conn = pymssql.connect(server=server, user=user, password=pas)
df = pd.read_sql(qtext, conn)
```

My profiler shows that the problem is in `execute()` method of pymssql

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
     1   51.896   51.896   51.896   51.896 {method 'execute' of 'pymssql.Cursor' objects}
```

How is that possible? I think the query text is not a bottleneck, the query is optimized and tested in SQL Management Studio.

Comment: SSMS is just a client, it doesn't optimize anything. How long does the query take to run from SSMS? What is the execution plan? Did you already encounter performance or blocking problems? Is this why you used `NOLOCK` to read dirty data?

Comment: What is `= %(user)s ` ? This isn't valid SQL. You can't run this query in SSMS which means you tested something different. Are you using string substitution to generate the final query, even though you fill the temporary table only with a single device's data?

Comment: %(user)s is just 12345

Comment: As I said, that's not valid SQL and it's not a parameter. Which means this isn't the query that was tried in SSMS. In any case, the `NOLOCK` statements are a very, very strong smell that suggests there are blocking issues. I suspect SSMS was used against a test database, while this query hits a production table.

Comment: This query can easily force full table scans, since temporary tables don't have primary keys and indexes. The join will have to scan both tables to find matching rows. A CTE wouldn't have to do that, it would use the original table's indexes. If a lot of devices write to the table, the query won't be able to take a shared lock on the entire table (required for a scan) for a long time. Using snapshot isolation would overcome this, but actually fixing the query would be even better

Comment: If you want to find the maximum coordinates for the latest date, why not use `GROUP BY rtp.[RichTrackId], rtp.PointDate HAVING PointDate=MAX(PointDate)` ? You don't need to generate temporary results for this

Comment: I want to find the maximum coordinates for the latest date for **each RichTrackId**

Comment: Yes. Which can be done with HAVING filters, CTEs or subqueries. No need to use temporary tables or NOLOCK. The problem is the query itself. In any case, if you want to troubleshoot a query *post the execution plan*. I'll bet you'll see full table scans

Comment: Aside from the query itself: You will *always* have additional latency when running a query across the Internet. You will be also be limited by bandwidth (and the VM's NIC). And the more data that comes back to the client, the slower things will become. As @PanagiotisKanavos said - it looks like you have some suboptimal attributes to your query which need some work. But don't expect it ever to run as fast as running from Management Studio on the same VM (or vnet) as the database VM.

Comment: @DavidMakogon that would affect SSMS too, it's just a client tool. This isn't the issue here

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - I was under the impression SSMS and the database engine were on the same network, vs Ubuntu in the cloud and database engine locally. At least that's how I interpreted the question.

Comment: @DavidMakogon the opposite: `I have an Ubuntu virtual machine in local network`. Although the OP didn't *specifically* say that SSMS runs locally. It would be unexpected to run SSMS on a cloud VM.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - ok. I'm bowing out. But... trivial to run SSMS from a Windows VM.